# How to verify deep equality of arguments passed to a Mockk mock?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

As it seems, Mockk mocks only store the reference to the received arguments for later verification. This poses a problem as soon as the argument becomes modified throughout the test. How could one verify a mock function invocation for deep equality of the arguments?

The following code snippet demonstrates the problem:

```
data class Entity(var status: String)

interface Processor {
    fun process(entity: Entity)
}

class ProcessorTest {
    @Test
    fun `should receive untouched entity`() {
        val myEntity = Entity("untouched")

        val processorMock: Processor = mockk()
        every { processorMock.process(any()) }.answers {
            println(firstArg<Entity>().status)
        }

        processorMock.process(myEntity)  // process untouched entity
        myEntity.status = "touched"      // afterwards it becomes touched

        verify { processorMock.process(Entity("untouched")) }
    }
}
```

`processorMock::process` is expectedly and apparently being called with an "untouched" entity, as it prints "untouched". However the verification fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Processor(#1).process(eq(Entity(status=untouched)))). Only one matching call to Processor(#1)/process(Entity) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: Entity(status=touched), matcher: eq(Entity(status=untouched)), result: -
```

I have tried using a `CapturingSlot` with no success, either.

Mockk version is 1.9.3, Kotlin version is 1.3.70. I am using JUnit 5 as a testing framework.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello @Heiko, did you find any solution ?